Using discovered online documentation, cannot render NotoSans fonts in react-native-paper ...DefaultTheme customization
UPDATE: This is a type error on DeepPartial and I got an answer using Copilot (AI) but I still don't understand from the response how I refactor my DeepPartial. Adding Typescript tag to issue.
I am using the DefaultTheme and then overriding colors and that works, when I added font customizations according to documentation I have found, I get a type error on PaperProvider theme. And, when I run npm run start the application, I don't get any rendering of the landing page. When I remove the font configuration from the theme override, I get the page but no custom fonts.
Can someone suggest a solution to the error on "theme" in the PaperProvider? Here's the error from WebStorm IDE.
Type '{ colors: { primary: string; onPrimary: string; primaryContainer: string; onPrimaryContainer: string; secondary: string; onSecondary: string; secondaryContainer: string; onSecondaryContainer: string; ... 24 more ...; backdrop: string; }; ... 6 more ...; isV3: true; }' is not assignable to type '$DeepPartial<MD3Theme>'.
Types of property fonts are incompatible.
Type Fonts has no properties in common with type $DeepPartial<MD3Typescale>
PaperProvider.d.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from property theme which is declared here on type IntrinsicAttributes & Props

This is App.tsx
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';
import MainNavigation from './src/navigation/MainNavigation';
import {ToastProvider} from 'react-native-toast-notifications';
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {en, registerTranslation} from 'react-native-paper-dates';
import {configureFonts, DefaultTheme, MD3LightTheme, MD3DarkTheme, PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {AxiosProvider} from './src/common/context/AxiosContext';
import './lang/i18n.config'; // internationalization

// TODO import Honeybadger from '@honeybadger-io/react-native';
const fontConfig = {
  web: {
    regular: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Regular',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    medium: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Medium',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    light: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Light',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    thin: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Thin',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
  },
  ios: {
    regular: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Regular',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    medium: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Medium',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    light: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Light',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    thin: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Thin',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
  },
  android: {
    regular: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Regular',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    medium: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Medium',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    light: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Light',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    thin: {
      fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Thin',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
  }
} as const; // This line ensures fontConfig is treated as a read-only object

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      primary: "rgb(207, 65, 36)",
      onPrimary: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      primaryContainer: "rgb(219,255,224)",
      onPrimaryContainer: "rgb(44, 0, 81)",
      secondary: "rgb(102, 90, 111)",
      onSecondary: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      secondaryContainer: "rgb(219,255,224)",
      onSecondaryContainer: "rgb(33, 24, 42)",
      tertiary: "rgb(128, 81, 88)",
      onTertiary: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      tertiaryContainer: "rgb(219,255,224)",
      onTertiaryContainer: "rgb(50, 16, 23)",
      error: "rgb(186, 26, 26)",
      onError: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      errorContainer: "rgb(255, 218, 214)",
      onErrorContainer: "rgb(65, 0, 2)",
      background: "rgb(208,224,232)",
      onBackground: "rgb(29, 27, 30)",
      surface: "rgb(154,186,186)",
      onSurface: "rgb(29, 27, 30)",
      surfaceVariant: "rgba(91,126,136,0.29)",
      onSurfaceVariant: "rgb(74, 69, 78)",
      outline: "rgb(124, 117, 126)",
      outlineVariant: "rgb(154,186,186)",
      shadow: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
      scrim: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
      inverseSurface: "rgb(50, 47, 51)",
      inverseOnSurface: "rgb(219,255,224)",
      inversePrimary: "rgb(220, 184, 255)",
      elevation: {
        level0: "transparent",
        level1: "rgba(208,224,232,0.75)",
        level2: "rgba(208,224,232,0.75)",
        level3: "rgba(208,224,232,0.75)",
        level4: "rgba(208,224,232,0.75)",
        level5: "rgba(208,224,232,0.75)",
      },
      surfaceDisabled: "rgba(29, 27, 30, 0.12)",
      onSurfaceDisabled: "rgba(29, 27, 30, 0.38)",
      backdrop: "rgba(51, 47, 55, 0.4)"
    },
  //fonts: configureFonts({config: fontConfig, isV3: false}),
  fonts: configureFonts({
    config: fontConfig,
    isV3: false,
  }),
};

const App = () => {
  console.log('Environment ' + process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT);
  console.log('Server URL ' + process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL);
  console.log('S3 URL: ' + process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_S3_URL);
  console.log('WEB URL: ' + process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_WEB_URL);
  if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
    //  Honeybadger.configure({
    //    apiKey: 'hbp_mA9akEG4Bz4BHwGzIWNQ5risUD2nws0OeS86',
    //  });
  }
  registerTranslation('en', en);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <ToastProvider placement="top">
        <RecoilRoot>
          <AxiosProvider>
            <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
              <MainNavigation />
            </PaperProvider>
          </AxiosProvider>
        </RecoilRoot>
      </ToastProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

